# Apache Kafka Exactly-Once implementation in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I just started learning the Apache Kafka. I'm using nodejs and node-rdkafka. In order to use Kafka's Exactly-Once feature, I only see java code, but I can't find a way to implement it with nodeJs.
Can this be done, if yes, how?

Comment: node-rdkafka (or more specifically, the underlying librdkafka client) supports exactly once producing using the idempotent producer.  See https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/INTRODUCTION.md#idempotent-producer. Full blown end-to-end/consumer EOS is scheduled for later.

Comment: Thanks! As far as I understand, "Idempotent producer" ensures that the message is only written once to topic. So there is no guarantee that the consumer will only and exactly read this message once. 
Is the "exactly-once" semantic in Kafka generally like this, or do the "idempotent producer" can provide only a part of this concept? 
In summary, is there a way to achieve a one-to-one message flow? is the name of this way "exactly-once", but is it not possible to implement it with nodeJs (with idempotent producer)? @Edenhill